# Using mutate to get an average of the previous weeks temperature

Tags: r, case, mutate

I'm looking for a way to create a new variable for an average of the temperature the week before.

I've got a data frame that looks like the following

weather_data

```
Rows: 3,664
Columns: 2
$ dt                  <date> 2014-01-01, 2014-01-02, 2014-01-03, 2014-01-04, 2014-01…
$ temp                <dbl> 6.390000, 6.234167, 6.307500, 4.436250, 4.432917, 8.4508…
```

What I'm hoping to do is get a new column called `prev.temp` that gives the average temperature for the previous week.

I know how to use mutate to create the new column but am struggling with the referencing. I can't group_by because the "week prior" is a rolling thing but I'm struggling with trying to reference the date for the observation and also the 7 dates of information I need.

My first thought was something like this: mutate(prev.temp = casewhen(date > date - 7, mean(temp))) but I'm sure its not right.

Comment: This is a window operation, supported by several non-base functions/packages (and can be done in base, if need-be). By "week before", do you mean a "rolling window" (Mon-Sun, Tue-Mon, Wed-Tue) or a "tumbling window" (Sun-Sat always, for the week prior to this week)?

Comment: @r2evans hello, I'm looking for a rolling window if possible! Thank you for this - I didn't even really know what to search for on google. Please let me know if you have further advice on how to achieve this

Comment: Okay, good information. So that means if "today" (this row) is `"2024-01-10"`, then you want `prev.temp` to be the mean of `temp` between `"2024-01-03"` and `"2024-01-09"`? Also, are you "guaranteed" to have all data, or is there the possibility of gapped weeks?

Comment: @r2evans yes exactly as you've said. All data is guaranteed as the data set is complete however I'd be interested to know what solution you'd suggest for gappy data too.  I've done a quick google and think it would be something along these lines: zoo::rollmean(data, k = 7, align = "right") however I'm still a bit confused on how to ensure that the current date's temp is not included in the mean.

Comment: Your data looks like it's a `tbl_df`, are you using `dplyr`?

Comment: @r2evans yes I'm using dplyr. Thanks for the formatting edits on my post too btw

Comment: Maybe you could add `dplyr::lag`? Hard to say without a small example. You could try sharing some data using `dput(head(weather_data, 14))` which would make it easier to help you. Possibly adding desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. A "rolling window" works well when you are "guaranteed" to have no gaps in your dates. One assumption here is that 1-row is always 1 day, so we rely on that being the case. Another assumption is that the data is pre-ordered by `dt`.

   We'll use `zoo::rollapplyr` here, width of 7. `partial=` means that during the first week of data, we'll still average those observations before today.

   ```r
   zoo::rollapplyr(weather_data$temp, 7, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE)
   #  [1] 9.233254 9.333467 7.414063 7.679054 7.498385 7.193965 7.256155 6.253119 5.893012 6.431630 5.952437 6.051908 6.586221 5.967587 6.388821 6.752706 7.103914
   # [18] 6.666444 6.352582 5.871288 6.705206 6.289171 6.352013 6.311438 6.266374 6.316793 6.098056 6.100250 6.496584 6.300014 6.031206 6.968000 6.805867 7.185110
   # [35] 6.025666 6.521882 5.456449 4.775102 4.897948 5.185524 4.792596 5.347797 4.325031 5.567295 5.855414 5.920953 6.275780 6.610605 7.298713 8.046237 7.223235
   ```

   Verifying the data, the first week of data should be in the 7th position of this vector (it is):

   ```r
   mean(weather_data$temp[1:7])
   # [1] 7.256155
   ```

   We need to lag this by one back into the data, so we can do

   ```r
   weather_data %>%
     mutate(prev.temp = lag(zoo::rollapplyr(temp, 7, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE)))
   # # A tibble: 51 × 3
   #    dt          temp prev.temp
   #    <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>
   #  1 2023-11-29  9.23     NA   
   #  2 2023-11-30  9.43      9.23
   #  3 2023-12-01  3.58      9.33
   #  4 2023-12-02  8.47      7.41
   #  5 2023-12-03  6.78      7.68
   #  6 2023-12-04  5.67      7.50
   #  7 2023-12-05  7.63      7.19
   #  8 2023-12-06  2.21      7.26
   #  9 2023-12-07  6.91      6.25
   # 10 2023-12-08  7.35      5.89
   # # ℹ 41 more rows
   # # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
   ```

   If you think you may have "gappy data", then all you need to do is interpolate the missing dates, give them a temp of `NA`, arrange by date, and then we are back to business with "guaranteed no gaps".

   ```r
   weather_data_gapped <- weather_data[-c(4, 8),]
   head(weather_data_gapped, 10)
   # # A tibble: 10 × 2
   #    dt          temp
   #    <date>     <dbl>
   #  1 2023-11-29  9.23
   #  2 2023-11-30  9.43
   #  3 2023-12-01  3.58
   #  4 2023-12-03  6.78
   #  5 2023-12-04  5.67
   #  6 2023-12-05  7.63
   #  7 2023-12-07  6.91
   #  8 2023-12-08  7.35
   #  9 2023-12-09  5.12
   # 10 2023-12-10  7.47
   weather_data_gapped %>%
     reframe(dt = seq(min(dt), max(dt), by="day")) %>%
     left_join(weather_data_gapped, by = "dt")
   # # A tibble: 51 × 2
   #    dt          temp
   #    <date>     <dbl>
   #  1 2023-11-29  9.23
   #  2 2023-11-30  9.43
   #  3 2023-12-01  3.58
   #  4 2023-12-02 NA   
   #  5 2023-12-03  6.78
   #  6 2023-12-04  5.67
   #  7 2023-12-05  7.63
   #  8 2023-12-06 NA   
   #  9 2023-12-07  6.91
   # 10 2023-12-08  7.35
   # # ℹ 41 more rows
   # # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
   ```

   (... and then do the `rollapply` thing as above.)
2. A non-equi join also works, perhaps more akin to your `case_when` thought.

   ```r
   weather_data %>%
     mutate(dt0 = dt, dt_from = dt - 8, dt_to = dt - 1, temp) %>%
     left_join(weather_data, join_by(between(y$dt, x$dt_from, x$dt_to)), suffix = c("", ".prev")) %>%
     summarize(prev.temp = mean(temp.prev, na.rm = TRUE), .by = c(dt0, temp)) %>%
     rename(dt = dt0)
   # # A tibble: 51 × 3
   #    dt          temp prev.temp
   #    <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>
   #  1 2023-11-29  9.23    NaN   
   #  2 2023-11-30  9.43      9.23
   #  3 2023-12-01  3.58      9.33
   #  4 2023-12-02  8.47      7.41
   #  5 2023-12-03  6.78      7.68
   #  6 2023-12-04  5.67      7.50
   #  7 2023-12-05  7.63      7.19
   #  8 2023-12-06  2.21      7.26
   #  9 2023-12-07  6.91      6.63
   # 10 2023-12-08  7.35      6.34
   # # ℹ 41 more rows
   # # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
   ```

   This method is resilient to gapped data as well as out-of-order data.

---

Sample data

```r
set.seed(42)
weather_data <- tibble(dt = Sys.Date() - 50:0, temp = runif(51, 1, 10))
head(weather_data, 10)
# # A tibble: 10 × 2
#    dt          temp
#    <date>     <dbl>
#  1 2023-11-29  9.23
#  2 2023-11-30  9.43
#  3 2023-12-01  3.58
#  4 2023-12-02  8.47
#  5 2023-12-03  6.78
#  6 2023-12-04  5.67
#  7 2023-12-05  7.63
#  8 2023-12-06  2.21
#  9 2023-12-07  6.91
# 10 2023-12-08  7.35
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help on this! All working now :)